# Conditional INSERT following a CTE clause in t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert, common-table-expression

I was curious why I can't seem to get a conditional statement to follow a common table expression in t-SQL statement?

Stuff like this:

```
WITH ctx AS(...)
IF ctx.v BEGIN
INSERT INTO ...
END
```

I made a [sample fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f656/28).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common table expression is basically just a subquery that can be reused in multiple SQL statements.  So, you would need to select from it in any case; you can't just reference it like it's a variable.  Think of it more like a temporary table.

You should be able to achieve what you want just by adding your criteria as a where clause.

```
WITH ctx AS(
   SELECT MIN(t1.dtIn) AS mdIn, MAX(t1.dtOut) AS mdOut FROM tbl t1
      INNER JOIN tbl t2
      ON t1.Type = t2.Type
        AND t1.dtIn < t2.dtOut 
        AND t1.dtOut > t2.dtIn
      WHERE t1.type = 1
)

INSERT INTO tbl (id, dtIn, dtOut, type)
SELECT 10, 
       CASE WHEN mdOut IS NOT NULL AND 
                 mdOut > '0:30' AND
                 '0:40' >= mdOut THEN mdOut
       ELSE '0:30' END,
       CASE WHEN mdIn IS NOT NULL AND
                 mdIn < '0:40' AND
                 '0:30' >= mdIn THEN mdIn
       ELSE '0:40' END,
1
FROM ctx
where ctx.mdIn < '0:40' AND ctx.mdOut > '0:30'

select * from tbl
```

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I was almost there :) Just from curiosity, does this mean that one can use WHERE on INSERT INTO?

Comment: @ahmd0 No, the where clause applies to the select, but it is effectively the same for your purpose.  In any case where you are using an insert...select construct, you can use a where clause to limit what is selected, and thus what is inserted.

Comment: You can use a where clause on an insert / select that doesn't have a from, e.g. `CREATE TABLE #x(i INT); INSERT #x(i) SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 0;`